# Select all values in a column from SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Could someone tell me how to get all the values in a column from my SQL Server database?

I have a table with the following structure:

**ELECTS**

- `SSN     int` (primary key)
- `NAME    varchar(20)`
- `PROGRAM varchar(max)`
- `PHOTO   varchar(max)`

And I want to retrieve all values from the `SSN` column and store them in an integer array in an ASP.NET project.

I using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 2010 and SQL Server 2008 SP3.

Answer (score 5):

```
string yourConnectionString = "......";
List<int> allSSN = new List<int>();

string sqlStmt = "SELECT SSN FROM dbo.Elects";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString) 
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
           int ssn = rdr.GetInt32(0);
           allSSN.Add(ssn);
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

At the end of this code, you have all the `SSN` column values in a `List<int>` for your use

Comment: You don't need the calls to `Close()`; `using` blocks ensure the resources are closed.

Comment: @Jacob, true, but I always prefer to clean up after myself irrespective.

Comment: @Jacob: the `using` ensures this - but I still like to explicitly close reader and connection - it's just good practice. The `using` blocks are just my "emergency backup"

Comment: Do you also explicitly run the GC?

Comment: If you explicitly call `Close` *and* use a `using` block, then `Close` gets run twice, which is less efficient.  No clarity or safety is added to the code; rather a reader would be confused, wondering if there was an important reason why you're doing both.

Comment: @Jacob: I disagree. I believe having explicit calls to `.Close()` is just good practice and makes sense. And I also do not think that close or dispose will be called twice (and even if they were called twice - **so what??**) - the `using` blocks are just a "backup" for when I forget... furthermore: all of this has **no impact** on the validity of the response in regards to what the OP was asking for...

Comment: I "agree with Jacob" as the using is supplanting the manual close, but still +1 for the answer ;-) [There are some cases -- e.g. when dealing with GZipStream where as Close is actually "required" in context unless there is some juggling of code, I consider it an ugly edge-case.]

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which is used on the StackOverflow site, and is available as a NuGet package (search for "Dapper dot net").

With Dapper you can use the following to get an `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> allSSN;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    allSSN = SqlMapper.Query<int>(connection, "SELECT SSN FROM dbo.Elects");
}
```

As a personal note, this was my first time taking Dapper for a spin; before this, I would have used a `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` as per @marc_s's answer, but I believe I'll be using Dapper in my future projects.